# Issue in applying Polaraid styles on Div's list

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I am bit new to CSS/bootstrap style programming.

I am trying to create a cards list, please refer the [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/snkrishnan1/2ntu4og2/19/) which I have created to show the lists. Now I wanted to apply the some Polaroid UI styles which would tilt/rotate the required objects randomly (please refer [link](http://zurb.com/playground/css3-polaroids)).

My requirement is to generate the list with the combination of both the styles. Please refer the snapshot for the expected output. I tried applying the Polaroid styles on top of the Div's List which I have generated but it doesn't apply correctly and it is not generating the required output.[image]

Can somebody help me in acheiving this? what is it I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem. Please find the solution in the [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/help-needed-in-applying-polaroid-styles-on-divs-list/243654/6) in some other forum